# Qt link to Ovi(Nokia) Store shop

Tags: c++, image, qt, qml, ovi

Is there any way I can let a qml image take users to the pro version if my app in the ovi store client once its clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same link as on the Ovi/Nokia Store website should open the store app on the device.

E.g.

```
Qt.openUrlExternally("http://store.ovi.com/content/198002")
```

opens the store app for the "4squick free" app. Tested on N9 but should also work on Symbian.